# read txt file with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code for reading files. Everything is OK with Chrome and FF, but IE does not update the data from the file ... seems to be reading from cache??? Any suggestions? Thanks

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","YOUR_FILE.txt",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Comment: How does jQuery fit in here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try adding a dynamic string argument to the end of the filename to prevent caching.

Try this:

```
var time = new Date().getTime();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "YOUR_FILE.txt?time=" + time, false);
```

Check out Javascript's [`Date.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537505(v=vs.85).aspx 
Microsoft suggests slightly different code:

```js
var xmlHttp = null;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  // If IE7, Mozilla, Safari, and so on: Use native object.
  xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
  if (window.ActiveXObject) {
     // ...otherwise, use the ActiveX control for IE5.x and IE6.
     xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
  }
}
```